# ImageMagic for android

Tags: android, imagemagick, android-ndk-r7

Hi i tried to compile https://github.com/lilac/Android-ImageMagick  library for android but it didn't work. Then i found out this library https://github.com/puelocesar/android-lib-magick which i don't need to compile. when i run this library it got installed on my galaxy 4.1 devices but didn't show anything but the black screen and after some time quits the app without showing any error in log cat. Can anyone tell me how to make this library working ?

Answer (score 0):

The library at https://github.com/puelocesar/android-lib-magick , is working.
You only have to replace the input filename with the name of your input file, which I guess, is missing, and that seems to be the reason behind your problem.

Hope, this will help you out.